# Save async a singleton property with realm

Tags: android, multithreading, realm

My question might be a little awkard:

## My scenario:

- I have a `singleton` which contains many references to my objects.
- I initialize this `singleton` in my activity running an `UI` operation with `Realm` with `realm.where(myobj.class).first();`
- In my `activity` I have a `ViewPager` with many `fragments`. Those `fragments` refers to the `Singleton's properties.`
- In my many `fragments`, I need to update some of my `singleton object properties`, but I want to do it with an **async transaction**. Obv it result on a thread realm error.

## Relevant code (cutted)

**singleton**

```
public class OpenedIntervention {

  private static OpenedIntervention openedIntervention;

  public static OpenedIntervention getIstance() {
    if (openedIntervention == null) {
        openedIntervention = new OpenedIntervention();
    }
    return openedIntervention;
  }

  public void dispose() {
    openedIntervention = null;
  }

  private Intervention intervention = null;
  //getter setter
}
```

**My activity init:**

```
//...
Intervention i = realm.where(Intervention.class).equalTo("ID", intId).findFirst(); //this realm istance has activity-scope
        openedIntervention.setIntervention(i);
//...
```

**My fragment, what I would like to do:**

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(
  new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
      //...
      openedIntervention.getIntervention().setTIPOLOGIA_INTERVENTO(etInterventionType.getText().toString());
      openedIntervention.getIntervention().setTIPOLOGIA_INTERVENTO_ID(etInterventionType.getTag().toString());
    }
  },
  new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
      //...
    }
  },
  new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable error) {
     //...
   }
 });
```

Any Idea about how can I solve this problem? I 'd like to do it async to avoid lag

Comment: What I feel is you will have to query for the result again from db and then update it inside `executeTransactionAsync()`

Comment: Saran is correct.

Comment: thanks, I found a workaround starting from your hint: I update the object async with a select query and after I call realm.refresh();  Thanks!